# How to execute shell command with && in groovy

Tags: python, groovy, virtualenv

I would like to execute the following shell command

```
workon foo && python /path/to/bar.py --parm1 /path/p1 --parm2 /path/p2
```

I've tried running it like this

```
    def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
    def proc = ["/bin/zsh","-c"," workon foo", "&&", "python", "/path/to/bar.py", "--parm1", "/path/p1", "--parm2", "/path/p2"].execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
    println "out> $sout err> $serr"
```

but I keep getting errors:

```
out>  err> zsh:1: command not found: workon
```

I can execute this command from the terminal

Comment: @JavaNut13 yeah, thats why I added the `/bin/zsh -c`

Comment: presumably `workon` is not in the $PATH ...

Comment: @donkopotamus thanks. had to append `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @donkopotamus suggested it's likely that `workon` is not in your path nor setup (via environment initialization) when `zsh -c` is called. It's likely that you need a "login shell" to do this -but note that I don't use or know much about `zsh` :)

Try running `zsh -l -c COMMAND`.

In addition, the way you're calling `zsh` with `-c`, it can only process one command. Everything else will be treated as arguments to that command.

To use `&&`, you'll have to assign this to `proc`:

```
["/bin/zsh","-lc", "workon foo && python /path/to/bar.py ..."]
```

Notice that the argument to `-c` is *one* string.